# Compare Get-Date to Date as String

Tags: powershell

The registry contains a key, with a string value much like:

```
23-01-2015 14-58-00
```

Using PowerShell I need to compare this date to ensure it is greater than the value returned from `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)`. However the formats are different, and I can't run a compare between the two, neither can I format the Get-Date as the `.AddDays` cannot run against a string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("23-01-2015 14-58-00","dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss",$null)

Friday, January 23, 2015 2:58:00 PM
```

This outputs a DateTime object. `"dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss"` is a specific mapping to your required DateTime format, using [DateTime format placeholders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for year, month, day, etc. If I didn't assume the correct format placeholders, just click that link above to find the ones you intended.

Afterwards, you can compare the two DateTime objects as you expected:

```
$myDate = [datetime]::ParseExact("23-01-2015 14-58-00","dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss",$null)
$myDate -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
True
```

Comment: Great, didn't even know about that!